# записать в <input> текст из <div>

Tags: jquery

на странице есть несколько элементов примерно такой структуры:

```
<div class="element">
  <div class="text-content">sometext</div>
  <div class="input-wrapper">
    <input type="text" name="someField">
  </div>
</div>
```

нужно при загрузке страницы в значение каждого `input` записать текст из текстового `div`, находящегося в том же элементе, что и `input`.

что-то вроде этого

```
$(window).load(function(){
  var fieldEls = $("input");
  fieldEls.each(function() {
    var elValue = $(this).parent().parent().find(".text-content").text();
    fieldEls.attr("value", elValue);
  })
});
```

записывает во все `input`ы содержание текстового `div.text-content`а, найденного в последнем элементе. что изменить, чтоб заработало?

ну и отдельно - как менее упоротым и в меньшей степени связанным со структурой разметки способом добраться до нужного дива?

Comment: может вместо `fieldEls.attr("value", elValue);` будет `this.attr("value", elValue);`

Comment: точно. только $(this).attr(). спасибо!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

из за конструкции `each` вожможно

вместо

```
fieldEls.attr("value", elValue);
```

будет

```
$(this).attr("value", elValue);
```